# Adding a MySQL driver library to a NetBeans project

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I'm pretty much new to Java EE programming, and I'm supposed to do some exercises (to finish my school pretty soon) about it.
My problem might be very simple, but I haven't found an answer whatsoever.
In one exercise, I'm supposed to be able to log in to a java/jsp/mysql-type of service.

Login.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h3>Login</h3>
<form name="login" method="post" action="ServletLogin">
<table>
    <tr> 
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Salasana</td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Log in;">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Pretty standard login, yes. When passing the form, it should go to a `ServletLogin.java` to initiate the login-sequence.
Instead I'm getting this from Glassfish:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1
```

In the `ServletLogin.java`, our tutor has left a note that the whole project should include a MySQL driver library to avoid `NullPointerException`.

My question is, how do I do that with Netbeans? Netbeans tells me I already have on installed, but apparently it either isn't or it doesn't work.

Here is `ServletLogin.java` code:

```
/*
 * Remember to install a MYSQL driver library
 * or the file will alert
 * NullPointerException.
 */

package Servlets; //the package in which the Servlet is part of.


import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "ServletLogin", urlPatterns = {"/ServletLogin"})
public class ServletLogin extends HttpServlet {

    Connection conn = null;

    /**
     * Initializes the servlet.
     */
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        //Connect to database with database-class
        try {
        conn = Classes.SQL.openConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Cannot connect to database " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroys the servlet.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    //Closing the database connection
         try {
          conn.close();
        } catch ( SQLException se ) {
           System.out.println("Exception " + se);
        }
    }

    //Everything is done in doPost method.
    //This Servlet does not use doGet() or ProcessRequest()

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {


    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    /*Unless there is a session, one is created.
        It is used to check if the user has logged in.*/

     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        //Reading the parameters from login form.
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        out.print(email);

        //Created login_ok and set it to false by default.
        boolean login_ok = false;


     try {
     //let's create a Statement with which the sql can be run with.
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

     //Run SQL and save it to ResultSet rs.
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT email, password FROM clients");

     //Go trough the results with while loop and next-method, which returns the value true, until we've reached last result.
     while(rs.next())
     {
       //Reading the data
       String email2 = rs.getString("email");
       String salasana2 = rs.getString("password);

       //If user input has been found from database,
       //login_ok becomes true and looping ends.
       if(email.compareTo(email2) == 0 && password.compareTo(password2) == 0)
       {
           login_ok = true;
           break;
       }

     }


     //If login_ok is true, save info about logging to session and guide the user to Clients.jsp
        if( login_ok == true )
        {
            //session is informed about login
            session.setAttribute("login", "ok");
            //Debugging printed to console.
            System.out.println("Login ok");
            //Proceeding to clients
            response.sendRedirect("clients.jsp");
            //Return stops the servlet run.
            return;
        }
      //Login false -> redirected to login page.
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.htm");
        }

    }

     catch(SQLException se){

     out.println("Error: " + se);

     }

        out.close();
    }


}
```

Am I missing something, like in imports or?
I've installed `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` and set it into multiple different places, with same result. All I need now is to be able to even see if the code works, but `NullPointerException` prevents me from doing so.
Adding the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` through **Project Properties -> Libraries** on Netbeans 8.0.2 doesn't seem to solve it, either.
Registered MySQL to GlassFish, still goes for `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Did you register mysql driver in Glassfish? [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html) you can find how to do that. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Dont iterate over a SQL result set like that. Its the databases duty to find a single record. Learn to use `SELECT ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Do you see "Cannot connect to database (...) " in server logs? Can you give more details about how you are trying to achieve the connection in Java?

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Services Tab
2. Select Databases
3. Right click and select Register MYSQL driver
4. Right Click libraries in project and select MYSQL from add Libraries

Comment: Doesn't allow to register MySQL Driver, the option is unavailable.